# jquery find option with dynamic value

Tags: jquery, node.js

For a node.js application, I have an ejs file with the following code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                //triggered when modal is about to be shown
                $('#editNodeModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {

                    var nodeGroups = $(e.relatedTarget).data('groups-id');
                    //alert(nodeGroups);

                    $(e.currentTarget).find('#nodeGroup option[value="???"]').attr("selected", "selected");

                });
</script>
```

This code get some data from the current page to automatically select options in a select list of a modal. If I replace the ??? with the value of an existing option in my select list, it works.

My question is :

I would like to replace the ??? with the nodeGroups value but I have no idea how to do it...
Can someone help me ?

Thanks you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply concatenate the `nodeGroups` value into your selector string:

```
var nodeGroups = $(e.relatedTarget).data('groups-id');
$(e.currentTarget)
   .find('#nodeGroup option[value="' + nodeGroups + '"]')
   .attr("selected", "selected");
```

For what it's worth, you can bring your code up to date jQuery-wise with a couple of adjustments, and shorten it at the same time:

```
$('#nodeGroup option[value="' + nodeGroups + '"]', e.currentTarget).prop("selected", true);
```

The above is basically:

```
$('selector', context);
```

Which is the same as

```
$(context).find('selector');
```

Use of `.attr()` changed in jQuery 1.7, which introduced `.prop()`. `selected` is a property of `option` elements, and thus should be changed with `.prop()`.

Comment: Depending on the jQuery version `.prop("selected", true)` - either way, +1

Comment: @tymeJV: I'll add it as a suggestion -- I left the non-relevant code intact.